# SQL aggregate functions where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to display the average marks of student where the average marks should be grater than 80. This is my code:

```
select 
    student_id, 
    round(avg(value), 2) as avg_mark 
from 
    mark 
where 
    avg_mark > 80 
group by 
    student_id 
order by 
    avg_mark;
```

There is a compilation error stating `avg_marks` in the `where` clause is an invalid identifier.

Comment: Use `having` and put it after the `group by`.

Comment: avg_mark doesn't exist in WHERE scope, because it is not a real column. Use HAVING as mentioned above.

Comment: Also, please format the query as code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `HAVING` to filter aggregation.

```
select student_id, round(avg(value),2) as avg_mark 
from mark
group by student_id 
having round(avg(value),2) > 80
order by avg_mark;
```

Answer (score 0):

avg_mark is not an existing column so you cannot use it in group by
You need to refer to it like avg(value)